# Preference: can I find the input type when the preference item is clicked

Tags: android, android-preferences

The Preference Screen XML; note that one preference is "numberDecimal".

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:key="tsName"
        android:title="@string/pref_common_test_name_title" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:key="tsSledWeightValue"
        android:title="@string/pref_cof_test_sled_weight" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The Preference onClick method: now I want to determine if that preference's input type is "numberDecimal", because I want to call custom editor.

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener sBindEditorToPreferenceClickListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        boolean isHandled = false;
        if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
// *******  CAN I FIND THE PREFERENCE'S "inputType" HERE?
// ******* EXAMPLE: if(preference.inputType == android:numberDecimal) {}
        }
        return isHandled;
   }
};
```

EDIT: Or is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
    EditText prefText = ((EditTextPreference) preference).getEditText();
    int type = prefText.getInputType();
    //do stuff
 )
```

Though it seems to be a bit strange. What are you really trying to do? Figure out which one was clicked? Just assign different click listeners.

Comment: vedavis commented: The goal is to call a custom editor for "numberDecimal". Both of your suggestions will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something like this:

```
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener sBindEditorToPreferenceClickListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        boolean isHandled = false;
        if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
            EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) preference;
            EditText editText = editTextPreference.getEditText();
            if( editText.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL ) {
                /**********************
                   Do your thing here 
                **********************/
                isHandled = true;
            }
        }
        return isHandled;
   }
};
```

The big difference between your code and the snippet above is that it's...

1. Casting `preference` to `EditTextPreference`
2. Grabbing the `EditText` from `editTextPreference`
3. Checking so that the input type of the `EditText` matches `InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL` (which corresponds to `android:numberDecimal` in XML)

You could probably write it more compact if you'd want to, but I chose to break it down so that it's easier to comprehend. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener sBindEditorToPreferenceClickListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        boolean isHandled = false;
        if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
              if (((EditTextPreference)preference).getEditText().getInputType()==InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL)
              {}
        }
        return isHandled;
   }
};
```

Available InputTypes: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

Comment: There isn't a method called `getEditText()` in the class `Preference`. However, `EditTextPreference` has the one you're looking for.

Comment: I wrote EditTextPreference as the OP too

Comment: Ok, I see your problem, I fix this